# Pointer or local variable for the output parameter of a function

Tags: c++, c++11

If I want to use the value of an element in a map as the output parameter of a function, is it better to declare it as a smart pointer or locally?

For example:

```
// .h
class A {
   private:
    // Is the below code preferred over 
    // std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<B>>?
    std::map<int, B> map;
   public:
    void Func1();
    // Message is the output parameter
    void Func2(int, B* message);
} 

// .cc
void A:: Func1() {
   B b;
   // Is it better to make b a smart pointer and use std::move 
   // to transfer the ownership to map?
   map.insert(std::make_pair(1, b));
   for (const auto& x : map) {
     Func2(x->first, &x->second);
   }
}
```

In the example above, is it better to declare a smart pointer for b and pass the pointer to Func2 instead?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no better way without knowing `B`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` makes copies of what you put in it<sup>1</sup>, so `map` owns the copy of `b` provided to `func2`. There is no need for smart pointers here as `map` will handle destruction of all stored `B`s.

In fact there is no need for pointers at all. `func2` could be `void Func2(int, B & message);` and use a reference.

<sup>1</sup> You can store a pointer in a `std::map`, and the `std::map` will contain a copy of the *pointer*. The data pointed at is not copied and needs external management to handle destruction. This is a good case for using a smart pointer, but storing pointers in a container defeats many of the benefits of using a container in the first place and is best avoided.